# ng-smart-table accessing current row in custom action

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

I want to customize custom action icon, something like this (pseudo-code):

```
    settings = {
        actions: {
            custom: [
                {
                    name: 'DOWNLOAD_PDF',
                    title: `
if this.row.status === 'one'
    <i class="nb-compose" title="Download PDF"></i>
else
    <i class="nb-compose" title="PDF is not downloadable yet"></i>
endif;
`
                },
            ],
        },
        ...
    }
```

Seems that ng2-smart-table only allows to output icon and no customization? Or is there any workaround?

ng2-smart-table version is 1.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that it finally boils down to 2 options:

- Defining column type=custom with renderComponent. No custom action then
- Rendering 2 icons, using rowClassFunction to set row classes and hide/show them appropriately